# jQuery mobile, PHP and ajax table reload on button click without page reload

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, jquery-mobile

I am currently making a web app and I have a pop up that when clicked I have that it closes but I also want it to refresh the table without refreshing the page. The pop up allows the user to modify data already in the table. So when the user clicks update the popup closes and then updates that column. But the problem I am having is that I have to do a physical page update to see the change.

Is there anyway of updating the table without refreshing the entire page.

This is the code that updates the records:

```
//updating appt details
        $('#updateDetails').click(function()
        {   

            var Update = $("#updateDetailsInput").val();


            $.post('DescUpdate.php', {AID:(ViewingID), NewDescription: Update}).done(function(data)
            {   
                $("#notesPopup").popup("close");
                $("#Table").reload();   


            });

        });
```

I have tried using the .reload function and also the refresh but I have not had much luck. Can anyone advise on what the best option is?

Comment: If I understood you right you want to update the table with the data from $.post. But you never push the new data into the table.

Comment: Sorry the data is pushed into the table elsewhere in the code. Each column corresponds to certain data inside the database. I am updating the details section of the table. Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#TableID").table("refresh");
```

Answer (score 0):

Figuring the php file you send post do return the table data in HTML as :

`<table>
[...]
</table>`

I would use do :

```
$.post('DescUpdate.php', {AID:(ViewingID), NewDescription: Update}).done(function(data)
        {   
            $("#notesPopup").popup("close");
            $("#Table").html(data);   


        });
```

Which is using the POST request result and input in as HTML in $("#Table") element